# git cap deploy: Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

i am  on windows and using capistrano (2.15.5). i am trying to push code to the server with command `cap deploy` but getting error as Permission denied (publickey) .

my public ssh key is already added to git account and i have also set the permission of the file to 600. but still i am getting this error.

Below is my error.

```
Permission denied (publickey).
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 and the repository exists.
```

Comment: have you added keys of your server?

Comment: where i have to add keys of my server??

Comment: ssh keys of server to git

Comment: No i have not added ssh keys of server to git account.. i have just added my desktop ssh key to git account... do i have to add server ssh key to git??

Comment: @Nithin - Thanks, i added server ssh key to git account and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use your private key to pull the code instead of adding the server key to github, by forwarding your SSH key while deploying

in your `deploy.rb`

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```